# Sequences of differentiable functions on various variables.

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

The following result is from single-variable calculus.

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval, an let $f_n:I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions. Suppose that there exists $x_0\in I$ such that $(f_n(x_0))$ is convergent, and $(f_n')$ exists and converges uniformly to a function $g$. Then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a differentiable function $f$, and $f'=g$.

Is it true on several variables (both on the domain and the codomain) under the same conditions?

Comment: I guess you mean partial derivatives? Then if the multi variable function is sufficiently nice it would hold because you can basically consider it as a one dimensional function.